# How to GROUP multiple records from two different SQL statements

Tags: sql

I have a table called **tbl** which contains all the data I need. I have many columns in this table, but for purposes of this example I will only list the columns necessary to accomplish this task.

Here's how data stored in the tbl *(note* uID is char(20) and cID is int)*:

> uID  cID
>
> 1     10
>
> 1     11
>
> 1     12
>
> 2     11

We usually query this table like

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE uID = "1"
```

So it returns

> uID  cID
>
> 1     10
>
> 1     11
>
> 1     12

But I also need to return the row where uID is different but cID do match. Or grab the uID of the second row (which is 2) based on cID and do a select statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE uID in ('1','2')
```

That query will return what I'm looking for

> uID  cID
>
> 1     10
>
> 1     11
>
> 1     12
>
> 2     11

This table contains a lot of rows and I want to be able to do this programatically for every call where cID matches and uID is different.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So, to clarify: are you trying to return records where uID is linked to records with the same cIDs?

Comment: That's correct. I could have three different uIDs, but they will have one cID that will join them together.

Comment: I added some code below. It could also be accomplished in CTE, but the idea is the same - find cIDs that have more than on uID linked to cID and then link it back to uIDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may be what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE uID = '1'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE uID <> '1' AND
      EXISTS (select 1 from tbl tbl2 where tbl2.uId = '1' and tbl2.cID = tbl.cID);
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain why are you grabbing 1 in your last statement in Exists case?

Comment: @user1426542 . . . You have to have something after the `select`, so I usually put `1` there.  I find `NULL` confusing.  And I `*` can be misleading, because in other contexts subqueries cannot return multiple columns.

Comment: Thank you. That explains it. But also could I return just the second uID based on the following query and having only the first uID. Currently it's returning multiple rows, but I want to just return the uID. This is something else I would want to do. But you answer will work for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

or something like this:

```
SELECT uID, cID
FROM tbl 
WHERE uID IN 
    (
        SELECT uID
        FROM tbl
        INNER JOIN 
            (
                SELECT cID
                FROM tbl
                GROUP BY cID
                HAVING count(*) > 1
            ) c ON c.cID = tbl.cID
    )
```

Comment: I'm not understanding what this query does. Once I run it, it returns me just uID and cID for that uID. I want to be able to pass one uID and it spits out the second uID where cID=cID

Comment: Well, in this case, the other answer suits you better. I thought you needed all the records where cIDs are linked to more than one uID.